# How to make layout with fixed sized column in Liferay?

Tags: html, css, layout, liferay

How to make layout with fixed sized column in Liferay?

I know how it is possible to style it with CSS, but where to put CSS files in Layout project?

May be there are matching styles in `aui.css` already and I can just use them somehow?

What is better: to embed style into `.tpl` file or use CSS files?

**FINALLY**

I just redefined styles for columns by id in my theme:

```
.columns-3 #column-1 {
    width: auto;
}

.columns-3 #column-2 {
    width: 840px;
}

.columns-3 #column-3 {
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to make layout with fixed sized column in Liferay?

You can use inline styles to fix the width of the columns within the `.tpl` file. Crude but works :-)

> I know how it is possible to style it with CSS, but where to put CSS files in Layout project?

I don't think you can have CSS files in a Layout. CSS files can go in theme. You can modify the `.tpl` with your custom CSS classes which will be present in your theme's CSS.

> May be there are matching styles in `aui.css` already and I can just use them somehow?

I don't think there are styles having fixed width which you can use and also this theme seems to be automatically generated when using AUI javascripts (as mentioned [in this post](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/17455523)).

> What is better: to embed style into .tpl file or use CSS files?

CSS files are always better since it gives you a lot of flexibility in changing the styles through different themes. So your layout would be dynamic based on the theme applied. Since styling basically is the job of the theme.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement you should create the layout with plugins sdk layouts, and that is more flexible.

If you feel to apply the CSS then you have to apply classes to the .tpl file and its respective CSS should be added to the theme custom.css file.

Just of curiosity, what type of fixed layouts are you creating.?